# group_by and count

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
@entries_by_source = Entry.joins(:training_entries).group("source_id, classification_id, category_id").select("source_id, classification_id, category_id, count(*) as entries_count")
```

These are in @entires_by_source

```
- !ruby/ActiveRecord:Entry 
  attributes: 
    source_id: 1
    classification_id: 1
    category_id: 1
    entries_count: 198
- !ruby/ActiveRecord:Entry 
  attributes: 
    source_id: 1
    classification_id: 1
    category_id: 2
    entries_count: 614
- !ruby/ActiveRecord:Entry 
  attributes: 
    source_id: 2
    classification_id: 1
    category_id: 3
    entries_count: 1
```

Now i'm trying to print something like that:

```
source_id entries_count
1          812 #sum of entries_count 198 + 614
2          1
```

The code below is not working. Any help will be appreciated

```
<% @entries_by_source.group_by(&:source_id).each do |source_id, entries_count| %>
  <%= source_id %><%= entries_count %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

group_by would return an array like

`[{'source_id_1' => [values, ...]}, {'source_id_2' => [values, ...]}]`

You'd need to sum the count, something like:

```
<% @entries_by_source.group_by(&:source_id).each do |source_id, entries| %>
  <%= source_id %><%= entries.sum(&:entries_count) %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 3):

Really good example here: http://markusjais.com/the-group_by-method-from-rubys-enumerable-mixin-and-compared-with-scal/

```
words = ["one", "two", "one", "three", "four", "two", "one"]
count = words.group_by { |w| w }.inject({}) do |tmphash, (k,v)|
      tmphash[k] = v.size
      tmphash
end
```